# What to set TIdSMTP.MailAgent to?

Tags: delphi, user-agent, indy, indy10

What should I set `TIdSMTP.MailAgent` to? Should I put my own app name, or mimic some 'famous' mail client (like Thunderbird)?

Does this make any difference in terms of spam score?

Comment: That is entirely dependent on what individual spam filters look for.  This is too broad to answer.

Comment: If I leave it blank , will Indy put anything on it ?

Comment: No, the `X-Mailer` header will be omitted.